# How do I make a constructor for a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, derived-class

I am trying to make a constructor for a derived class. Doing it this way doesn't seem to work:

```
#include <iostream>

class FirstClass
{
public:
    int X;
    FirstClass(int x)
    {
        this->X = x;
    }
    int getXpow() { return pow(X, 2); }

};

class SecondClass : FirstClass
{
public:
    SecondClass(int x)
    {
        FirstClass::FirstClass(X);
    }

    int getXpow() { return pow(X, 3); }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    FirstClass FCobj(3);
    cout << FCobj.getXpow() << endl;
    SecondClass SCobj(3);
    cout << SCobj.getXpow() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

because it says at the first `{` bracket of `SecondClass(int x)` the following thing `Error: no default constructor exists for class "FirstClass"`. And how does constructor inheritance even work?

Comment: You use member initializer list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the member initializer list:

```
SecondClass(int x) : FirstClass(x) {
}
```

Comment: Oh... I tried it before asking the question but the wrong way like this `SecondClass(int x) : FirstClass(int x)`, why is it that variable type is not required there?

Comment: @ĬnfernalSeraphím Because it's already typed and passed as parameter actually.